# Laravel Password Reset não está funcionando com model de Usuário customizado

Tags: php, autenticação, laravel-5.4

Estou tentando usar o sistema de autenticação Laravel com algumas customizações.

Este é o meu model de Usuário:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'csrh.usuarios'; 

    protected $fillable = [
        'nm_completo',
        'username',
        'password',
        'tp_usuario',
        'status_usuario'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;    

    public function servidor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('CSRH\Servidor', 'id_usuario');
    }    

    public function getEmailForPasswordReset() {            
        return $this->servidor->e_mail;
    }        

    /**
     * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
     */
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
        if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute) {
            parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }
```

}

O e-mail do usuário está na tabela 'servidor', no campo e_mail.

Quando eu clico no botão 'Redefinir senha', eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERRO: coluna "email" não existe
LINE 1: select * from "csrh"."usuarios" where "email" = $1 limit 1
^ (SQL: select * from "csrh"."usuarios" where "email" = 
abshire.eladio@example.net limit 1)
```

Eu tentei implementar o contrato CanResetPassword, mas cai no mesmo problema.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Bem-vinda, esse problema é porque não tem a coluna `email` em sua tabela, no banco de dados, deves cria-la.

Comment: Obrigada! Embora isso resolva o problema, é uma solução que eu não gostaria de usar, para não gerar redundância no meu banco de dados.

Comment: Você está utilizando `Migrações` ?

Comment: Posta o controller.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Só a migração para a tabela password_resets, sem alterações.

Comment: @DiegoSouza estou usando os controllers de autenticação que vem com o Laravel, sem alterações.